# Export a subclassed UIViewController with btouch

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I am trying to export *Cordova* into *Monotouch*. For the most part it is working, but the issue that I am encountering is that the delegate methods for `CDVViewController` (which is derived from *UIViewController*) do not fire. Neither the delegate methods defined in `CDVViewController` nor the events that I define *Monotouch* (ie a class derived from `CDVViewController`) seem to fire.

Here is some code; first snippets of the *Cordova* code that I am trying to export:

*CDVViewController.h:*

```c
@interface CDVViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate, CDVCommandDelegate> {    
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CDVCordovaView* webView;
```

*CDVViewController.m:*

```c
@implementation CDVViewController

@synthesize webView;

- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%s","Cordova viewDidLoad");
}
```

My *btouch* definition is as follows:

```cs
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Omnimove.Web.Cordova
{
    [BaseType(typeof(UIWebView))]
    interface CDVCordovaView 
    {
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
    interface CDVViewController 
    {
        [Export ("webView")]
        CDVCordovaView WebView { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my class that derives from *CDVViewController* in *Monotouch*:

```cs
public class UIFormsViewController : CDVViewController
{           
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {       
        Console.WriteLine (@"UIFormsViewController ViewDidLoad()");
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```

As I mentioned at the start, the code does compile and the *UIFormsViewController* does display its containing *CDVCordovaView* (*UIWebView*), but the *ViewDidLoad* defined in *UIFormsViewController* and the *viewDidLoad* defined in *CDVViewController* do not seem to fire at all. Can anyone explain why this is and how I would go about correcting this?

Answer (score 1):

If there's a `viewDidLoad` implemented in `CDVViewController` (and there IS one), make sure you expose it in your bindings, so the C# will have it as well and will think about calling it, instead of skipping to its parent.

Something like this should do it:

*ApiDefinition.cs*

```cs
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Omnimove.Web.Cordova
{
    [BaseType(typeof(UIWebView))]
    interface CDVCordovaView 
    {
    }

    [BaseType (typeof (UIViewController))]
    interface CDVViewController 
    {
        [Export ("webView")]
        CDVCordovaView WebView { get; set; }

        [Export ("viewDidLoad")]
        void ViewDidLoad ();
    }
}
```